# How does verilog evaluate conflicting assignments?

Tags: verilog

Is code like the following legal or would this give undefined behavior in case reset is set?  Would the compiler turn the initial assignment into a conditional or first increment the counter, then reset to 0? If this is executed sequentially, how are these sequential relationships represented in hardware?

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  counter <= counter + 1;

  if (reset)
    counter <= 0;
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is legal. Within an `always` block the order of the statements matter; thus in your case assignment of `counter <= 0` in case `reset` signal is set will override `counter <= counter + 1` assignment.

> Would the compiler turn the initial assignment into a conditional or first increment the counter, then reset to 0?

Most probably it will be realized as logic with register `counter` update source select signal.

> If this is executed sequentially, how are these sequential relationships represented in hardware?

No not *executed*. Verilog is not a programming language, it is describing hardware - electronic circuits. Thus this code you wrote will be converted to logic elements and registers, not to opcodes to execute.

The order of statements in `always` block are treated by *Verilog compiler* sequentially. Two examples

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  counter <= counter + 1;
  if (reset)
    counter <= 0;
end
```

with `counter <= 0` overriding `counter <= counter + 1` if `reset` is 1;

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  if (reset)
    counter <= 0;
  counter <= counter + 1;
end
```

with counter always ending with `counter <= counter + 1` because this statement appears after previous conditional statement. I think compiler must throw warning for this code because it must see that previous statement is never in effect.

Even more, this statement order in `always` is a feature, and you can use it to your benefit having some default action on the register (like in your case increasing register value), and overriding actions in specific circumstances (like in your case - resetting this register).

Answer (score 2):

As Anonymous said: the last assignment wins. I use this a lot to make state machines more readable. Instead of making an assignment in each state, I make one at the top and only overwrite it where it it needed. But I always add a comment with 'Defaults' in it to alert the user that those assignment will be overridden further down. Here is an extract from a UART, the transmit FSM.

```
//
// Transmit FSM
//

// Defaults for TX FSM
nxt_tx_state    = tx_state;
nxt_tx_bit_cnt  = tx_bit_cnt;
nxt_tx_samp_cnt = tx_samp_cnt;
nxt_shift_out   = shift_out;

case (tx_state)
TX_IDLE :
   begin
     // wait for write to TX register
     // catch the write data and go wait for a tick
     ser_out = 1'b1;
     if (cpu_write & data_select)
     begin
        nxt_shift_out  = cpu_wdata[7:0];
        // if (samp_tick).. could go straight to TX_SS
        // but this is a short wait and saves logic
        nxt_tx_state   = TX_TICK;
     end
   end
TX_TICK :
   begin
      // wait for sample tick
      nxt_tx_samp_cnt = 3'h0;
      nxt_tx_bit_cnt  = 3'h0;
      ser_out =  1'b1;
      if (samp_tick)
         nxt_tx_state = TX_SS;
   end
TX_SS :
   // combined start/stop state
   // Saves one FF in state
   // Re-using 3 bit comperator from TX_DATA
   begin
      ser_out = (tx_bit_cnt==3'h7) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
      if (samp_tick)
      begin
         nxt_tx_samp_cnt = tx_samp_cnt + 3'h1;
         if (tx_samp_cnt==3'h7)
         begin
            if (tx_bit_cnt==3'h7)
               nxt_tx_state = TX_IDLE;
            else
               nxt_tx_state = TX_DATA;
         end
      end
   end
TX_DATA :
   begin
      ser_out = shift_out[0];
      if (samp_tick)
      begin
         nxt_tx_samp_cnt = tx_samp_cnt + 3'h1;
         if (tx_samp_cnt==3'h7)
         begin
            nxt_shift_out= {1'b1,shift_out[7:1]}; // LS first
            if (tx_bit_cnt==3'h7)
               nxt_tx_state = TX_SS;
            else
               nxt_tx_bit_cnt = tx_bit_cnt + 3'h1;
         end
      end
   end
endcase // Transmit FSM
```